# Create control constructs without funny restrictions on line breaks in Scala DSL

Tags: scala

I'm writing a simple DSL for design by contract.  Here is what I would like to be able to write:

```
def incrX( i : Int ) {
      val x0 = x 
      pre( i >= 0 )
      post( x == x0+i )
      in {
          x += i 
      } }
```

So far what I've done is to make `pre` a trait method that takes a Boolean and returns an object. That object has a method `post` that takes a Boolean and returns another object. That object has a method `in` that takes a Unit and returns (). With that scheme I can write

```
def incrX( i : Int ) {
      val x0 = x 
      pre( i >= 0 ) post( x == x0+i ) in { x += i } }
```

or

```
def incrX( i : Int ) {
      val x0 = x 
      pre( i >= 0
      ) post( x == x0+i
      ) in {
          x += i 
      } }
```

or even

```
def incrX( i : Int ) {
      val x0 = x 
      (pre( i >= 0 )
       post( x == x0+i )
       in {
          x += i 
      } ) }
```

which are nice, but not quite what I'd like.

**Is there any way to accomplish what I'd like?**

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have for example to require `&` or `with` between the `pre` and `post` parts?

Comment: Scala has a built-in API that you can use like: `def incrX(i: Int) = { val x0 = x; require(i >= 0); (x += i) ensuring (x == x0 + i); }`

Comment: @GáborBakos I might, if there is no alternative.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner That is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of nice looking code I like the concept of "dot alignment", which is very common in Scala and solves your syntactical issues.

So given something like the following:

```
object Contract {
  def pre(c: => Boolean) = new ContractWithPre(c)
}
class ContractWithPre(preCond: => Boolean) {
  def post(c: => Boolean) = new ContractWithPreAndPost(preCond, c)
}
class ContractWithPreAndPost(preCond: => Boolean, postCond: => Boolean) {
  def in(body: => Unit) {
    require(preCond)
    body
    ensuring(postCond)
  }
}
```

You can write:

```
Contract
  .pre(i >= 0)
  .post(x == x0+i)
  .in {
    x += i 
  }
```

Comment: I like the answer, but it doesn't definitively answer my "can this be done" question.  Instead it excellently answers the obvious follow-up question "If it can't be done as I would like, what other ways are there to create a similar syntax."

Comment: @Theodore Norvell: If you're asking for "can this be done without _any_ modification to the code" (as in: change the behavior of the parser by some external modification), then my answer would be: No, I currently don't see any possibility besides, well, modifying the parser. That said, I still think that what you want is possible, simply by a very minor syntactical modification :).